# Facebook Multikey match api request struct?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am consuming the facebook ads api, I was able to send a list of emails, however in order to increase the matches, I want to send more information about the target user by using the multikey match feature and send the email, firstName, lastName.

My first question is: I believe for each record I will send, Facebook will apply a OR logic, meaning if the lastname is nor the correct but I have the correct email, FB targets the person by using the email and dismiss the other fields: firstname, lastname. Is it correct?

Could I send in the same batch empty values for records that I do not have their firstname or lastname for example?